# Is there a specific way(query) to find row count for all tables in a database with condition for one year or so?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

Is there a specific way(query) to find row count for all tables in a database with condition for one year or so ??

I want to get count of all tables in a database for each year separately

System: SQL SERVER 2016

Comment: your requirement is not clear. Please include your table schema, sample data and expected result. Also include your current attempt query

Comment: @squirrel: just simple, I have 100 tables in a database in which I want to see all the tables row count for each year !! In one single query. I know there is way to pull all row count but is there any for specific timeframe ?

Comment: No way. Unless you are doing this every year and stored the result somewhere. Or you have a `date` column in the table that you can use that to determine

Comment: Assuming all your tables share the exact same name for the date column such as "CreatedDate" etc you *could* construct a dynamic SQL query. Include some examples of your tables' schema in your question.

Comment: What does "for each year" mean? Do you have a date column on each table or something? Do all your tables have the same columns? (if so, why? sounds like a bad design) Please be clear.

Answer (score 0):

The below will let you define the name of the specific *Date* column you want to use and will construct a SQL statement to select the count of rows, grouped by year, for each table that contain a column with the specified name.

```
declare @Datecolumn sysname='CreatedDate', @Sql nvarchar(max)='';

select  @sql += Concat(
    'select ' , '''', 
    Concat(QuoteName(TABLE_SCHEMA),'.',QuoteName(TABLE_NAME)), '''',
    ' as TableName,',
    ' year(',
    QuoteName(@datecolumn),
    ') as [Year],',
    ' Count(*) as [Rows]',
    ' from ',
    Concat(QuoteName(TABLE_SCHEMA),'.',QuoteName(TABLE_NAME)),
    ' group by year(',
    QuoteName(@datecolumn),
    ')',
    ' order by year(',
    QuoteName(@datecolumn),
    ');
    '
    )
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where column_name=@Datecolumn

--print @sql /* testing */

exec sp_executesql @sql
```